# Akka Cluster Client communication over Service cluster IP Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, akka

I have deployed akka cluster in EKS and it is forming a cluster. I am making couple of rest calls to the cluster on a port 27520 and I am using cluster client to send it over to another akka cluster over clusterIP.

I see in the logs that it is getting the right service IP , but fails to communicate with the pods tied to the service IP.

I get the below error

```
    initialContacts: Set(akka://controller@194.169.252.192:8080/system/receptionist)
MktoClusterClientPoolActor: getClusterClientPool succeeded, setting retires to 1

[WARN ] [a.r.a.InboundHandshake$$anon$2]  - Dropping Handshake Request from [akka://controller@101.65.16.86:25520#-3378415211190166853] addressed to unknown local address [akka://controller@194.169.252.192:8080]. Local address is [akka://controller@101.65.16.86:25520]. Check that the sending system uses the same address to contact recipient system as defined in the 'akka.remote.artery.canonical.hostname' of the recipient system. The name of the ActorSystem must also match.

Service IP : 194.169.252.192
Pod IP: 101.65.16.86

Service port : 8080
Akka remoting port: 25520
```

I have defined service-settings.yaml where I associated ports:

```
ports:
- port: 8081
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 27520
  name: http
- port: 8080
  protocol: TCP
  targetPort: 25520
  name: remoting
```

Also, I can see under service in kubernetes dashboard that my ports are tied to it.I can port forward to my service locally and make a rest endpoint call that goes to one of the pods, but then the cluster client has difficulty in sending the request over to another akka cluster even after resolving the right IP address of the service.

I was going to the akka documentation but was confused whether it would help me : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html#akka-behind-nat-or-in-a-docker-container

Should I defined cononical host and port as my service host (controller) and port? and what should I defined by bind host and port as?

NOTE: I am aware cluster client is no longer supported and we should move to grpc. However, thats a lot of work which was not considered earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve the desired results (without switching to grpc) by directly connecting to pods. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/discovery/kubernetes.html. And refreshing the cluster client if the pod goes down.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't deploying your cluster client _inside_ the cluster? I guarantee you that anything outside the cluster is not able to connect with the pod IPs directly.

Comment: I have cluster client inside the cluster talking to a cluster which is in the same namespace but a different akka service service

Answer (score 0):

Cluster client is going to want to communicate directly with the cluster members (i.e. the pods). Exposing the Akka cluster as a K8S ClusterIP service isn't going to help because the Akka cluster is just going to help the client figure out which Akka node to communicate with. At which point the cluster client will try to access the internal IPs. (Which it both won't have access to and be a cluster internal range anyway.)

Fundamentally your only option is to have some kind of "bridge", whether that is gRPC, something homegrown (like a REST API) or something else. (Or to keep everything in the same cluster and allow the client to communicate directly with the pods.)

Comment: Wont it work if I have something of this sort?    remote {
      artery {
        transport = tcp                     # default
        canonical {
          hostname = "0.0.0.0"             # external (logical) hostname
          port = 25520                       # external (logical) port
        }
        bind {
          hostname = "0.0.0.0"
        }
      }

Comment: The above config would allow to resolve the IP address issue, right? I can be more specific and add canonical host name as ${SERVICE_IP} and bind host ${POD_IP}

Comment: No, because then the cluster client would try to connect to the internal K8S IP, which would not be addressable outside the cluster. I'm running an FTP server in my home on 192.168.0.99. But if I share that IP address with you still can't connect to it because that IP is internal to my home network. It's the same with K8S.

The cluster client will connect to the service IP, get a random Akka node and the Akka node will tell the cluster client "your Akka actor is available  at 192.168.0.99" and then it will fail because it can't reach that internal IP.

Comment: I'd note that the above _would_ work if the cluster client and the cluster are in the same cluster. It would let the Akka node bind to 0.0.0.0, but properly transmit its pod ip to other pods. (Presuming that there's no NetworkPolicy or similar blocking the traffic.)